# Как прибавлять каждый день определенное число через php в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.
Мне нужно что бы ежедневно в бд прибавлялась число. К примеру прошли сутки и +1. На данный момент я написал код, но в бд добавляется каждый раз когда обновляю страницу.

```
$dateStart = new DateTime($result['date']);
$now = new DateTime();
$number = $result['Price'] ;
$diff = $dateStart->diff($now)->format('%R%a');

       $bal = $number * $step * $diff;
$zd=$bal+$userdata['balans'];
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `users` SET `balans` = '$zd' WHERE `user_id`= {$userdata['user_id']}");
```

Comment: Думаю вам нужен Cron

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста пример кода

Comment: неужели **так трудно** написать в браузере прибавлять каждый день определенное число через php в mysql и сразу получить миллион ответов на свой вопрос?

Comment: Написал. Результат вы видите сверху. Только прибавляет он не каждый день, а при каждом обновлении страницы

Comment: написать **в браузере**. браузер - это программа через которую ты пишешь сюда. у него есть адресная строка. если в ней написать свой вопрос, то тебе сразу покажет миллион готовых ответов

Comment: Я же говорю. Я так и сделал. Результат выше

Comment: не надо каждый день что то прибавлять. фиксируйте в БД дату когда последний раз добавляли. Когда потребность в данных действительно возникнет, например пользователь посетит сайт, смотрите сколько дней прошло и сразу добавляете кол-во дней умноженное на сумму. И в эту же операцию не забываете поправить дату изменения баланса. Кроме того это надо сделать единым запросом mysql, а не получать в php, считать и писать, иначе за время между чтением и записью баланс может изменится и вы что нибудь затрете.

Comment: что то вроде `update users set balans = balans + datediff(curdate(), upd_date) * X, upd_date=curdate() where userid = Y`

Comment: @kas вы явно не так сделали, вы просто обновляете и да это при каждом обновлении страницы. в любом случае надо запоминать обновляли или нет что бы второй раз этого не делать

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Опыта мало в этом. Сейчас попробую. ваш совет